# Jenkins Crontab as variables

Tags: jenkins, cron

good morning.
I need to know if it is possible in jenkins,  that the values for the crontab are received as variable. For example, to execute the build you request, hour minutes, day, month and day of the week, as execution parameters. Then those values, pass them as variables to crontab. Is this possible?  I have try this in Jenkins but it doesn´t accept variable.

Comment: did you find a solution to your issue?

Answer (score 0):

With jenkins pipeline job you can define parameters in a declarative way as documented at

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        string(name: 'HOUR', defaultValue: '1', description: 'the hour')
    }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                sh """
echo "It is ${params.HOUR}"
"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters